# I want to prove that these definitions of expected value hold

Tags: probability, self-study, density-function, expected-value

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal B,P)$ be a probability space. I have two (related) questions.  Assuming that $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable, and understanding that

$$E(g(X)) = \int_{\Omega}g(X(\omega))dP(\omega),$$

how do I prove that these equalities hold for the two following circumstances?

First, $X$ is discrete, with range $\{x_{i}:i\in \mathbb N\}$. Then

$$E(g(X))=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}g(x_{i})P(X=x_{i}),\ \  \text{ provided } \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}|g(x_{i})|P(X=x_{i})<\infty.$$

Second, $X $ is absolutely continuous with density $f.$  Then

$$E(g(X))=\int g(x)f(x)dx\ \ \text{ provided }\int |g(x)|f(x)dx<\infty.$$

Comment: You might find these [recent slides from the ETH by Florian Herzog](http://www.idsc.ethz.ch/Courses/stochasticsystems/Probability.pdf) to be helpful: they cover all this material (and much more) starting from first principles in a very clear manner.

Comment: @whuber.thanks for slides but I know all this definition I can not Connection this consept.

Comment: What is nice about the slides is that in the pages before stating your problem (slides 19-29) it collects all the definitions that are relevant to the proof, which is a matter of applying these definitions.  That might help guide your investigation.  At what point are you stuck?

Comment: @whuber.I think about number one I can write $$E(g(X))=\int_{\mathbb R}g(X)dP$$ As regards $X$ is  discrete I think $$E(g(X))=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}g(x_{i})\int dP=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}g(x_{i})P(X=x_{i}) $$if it possible You Judge about number one

Comment: Because the equations you have written down do not make much sense, it looks like you would profit from a review of Lebesgue integration.